# Python regular expressions engine and parenthesis in pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a driver to handle a specific type of prompt from a terminal that I ssh into.

The code in the driver is looking for a particular pattern received from the device to know when to send additional commands or exit, etc.

The code in the driver takes the pattern as a regular expression. I've tried numerous different combinations of patterns for the regex to handle this prompt `'(Cisco Controller) >'`, but to no avail. I've tried to escape the parenthesis `'\(Cisco Controller\)\s*>'`, I've tried with raw string 
`r'\(Cisco Controller\)\s*>'`, and I've tried multiple other combinations, but I usually end up with the error "Unbalanced Parenthesis" or "Bogus escape character". Why can't I get the regex engine to accept this pattern?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the text from the actual pattern and for got to insert the backslashes that I did infact use to try and escape the parenthesis. '\(Cisco Controller\)\s*>' and r''\(Cisco Controller\) \s*>'

Comment: Wow, when I paste the pattern into the reply box it removes the backslashes. Interesting. In any event, I have tried a backslash both before the left and right parenthesis and using raw string.

Comment: (Edited question to correctly show the code)

Comment: The raw string version looks correct. How are you doing the matching?

Comment: In my code, I import the driver for the type of device I'm connecting to, and then use SSH2() to start a session. The remote terminal sends data back, and the driver parses the data for this pattern '(Cisco Controller) >'. When it sees this pattern it should interpret it as a prompt and execute the next statement in my code which would be to send another command or whatever. I have this working for several other terminal types, but this one type that has the parenthesis in the pattern of the prompt has become a headache.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the raw version of the string that you posted... When tested on the string `'(Cisco Controller) > Command to execute would be here'` It appears to match just fine.

```
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jun  9 2012, 11:30:32)
[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\(Cisco Controller\)\s*>')
>>> match = regex.search('(Cisco Controller) > Command to execute would be here')
>>> match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff3e720>
>>>
```

Comment: Well, it takes the regex, but then when it loads the regex from the driver during runtime, it flakes out with the errors "Unbalanced Parenthesis" or "Bogus escape character". I'm fairly new to Python, so forgive any ignorance on my part.

Comment: What driver? If this is something you are writing can you provide us with a code sample as to where you are "loading the regex from the driver"?  You need to give us some kind of concrete information about what you are doing or else this is the best I can do for you

Comment: Okay, I got it working. If I run the regex like this '[re.compile(r'\(Cisco Controller\)\s*>', re.I)]' instead of like this 're.compile(r'\(Cisco Controller\)\s*>', re.I)' it works. So, thanks to everyone who provided some feedback. I was pulling my hair out with the regex, and the confirmation that the regex pattern was accurate at least pushed me to look elsewhere for the issue, so thanks for that.